# Visual Studio unit test fails calling function in nuget package even though same call from application works C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, signnow

Let me start with what I don't believe the problems are.  The problem is not with the Nuget package(directly at least), the problem isn't with SignNow API(that's where I'm failing), probably isn't with any of the settings for connecting.

What's happening is I have a Unit Test that now exactly mirrors my application code in connecting to SignNow to pull my token.  When I make the call:

JObject OAuthRes = SignNow.OAuth2.RequestToken( UserId, Password, "*" );

from my application, it's great.  When I make the same call from my UnitTest, it returns null.  The funny thing is, SignNow tells me their function never returns null.  If I attempt to step into the RequestToken function from the UnitTest, it just steps over it.  I'm using the same Nuget Package for SignNow in both projects ( these are projects within the same solution, using shared code ) and has the same userid/password passed in.  My best guess is that the build of the Unit Test is somehow failing to link to the SignNow library correctly.  I've seen this sort of thing on older C++ compilers before.  To fix, I attempted to roll back my Git repo to code when it used to work and it still failed.

I'm looking for some clues in how a function that works correctly in one build could fail in the unit test when all the code run is the same.

Comment: Issue may be 32 bit vs 64 bit. But first: what version of .NET? What are your build settings? What unit test runner?

Comment: And what nuget package and version does your code depend on? Also could be that the SigNow is mocked in the unit test project, mocking frameworks typically default to null...

Comment: Is your test project targeting a different framework version than your other project? Is there a yellow triangle on any of the dependency references?

Comment: No mocking used, had that pointed out and already looked into it.  
Test project is pointed at the same version as the application, thought I made that clear.
Good thought on yellow triangles.  I checked and don't see any.  I'll compare DLL's in the actual bin folders to see if they match